# Java/Mysql Selecting Primary Key values from one table and Insert them to another table as Foreign Keys

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am creating a program which is a Car Management app in Java using Swing in Netbeans, and as the database I am using Mysql, which will do all the CRUD operation. I have created a database with 3 different tables.

DATABASE SCHEMA

```
CREATE TABLE car_make(
  make_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  make VARCHAR(50)
  PRIMARY KEY(make_id)
)

CREATE TABLE car_model(
  model_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  model VARCHAR(50)
  fk_make_id INT
  PRIMARY KEY(model_id)
  FOREIGN KEY(fk_make_id) REFERENCES car_make(make_id)
)

CREATE TABLE car_attributes(
  car_attr_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  fk_make_id INT
  fk_model_id INT
  year INT
  body_type VARCHAR(50)
  mileage INT
  price DECIMAL(6,2)
  PRIMARY KEY(car_attr_id )
  FOREIGN KEY(fk_make_id)  REFERENCES car_make(make_id)
  FOREIGN KEY(fk_model_id) REFERENCES car_model(model_id )
);
```

The `car_make` table is already populated with all the car makes which I inserted manually and their ID's were auto generated. And the `car_model` table is also populated with different models for each make.

I have also created the user interface in netbeans using Java Swing, where the user selects the make of the car which will automatically generate the corresponding model, the year, mileage and so on and insert all that data into the `car_attribute` tables. My question is, what is the query to  insert the car make and model into the `car_attribute` table as foreign keys. For example if the user chooses as Make-BMW and Model-5 Series, I want to insert both of those IDS into the third table.

Comment: `fk_make_id` shouldn't be in `car_attributes` as the make can already be determined via the model, which is defined by `fk_model_id`. Having both columns can lead to contradicting data like Passat as model and BMW as make instead of VW.

Comment: How does the user choose the model (and make)? Id expect some dropdown or similar where you should already have the IDs? You can fetch the IDs along when fetching the other data to populate the drop down. Then it's just a simple `INSERT INTO car_attributes (fk_model_id, ...) VALUES (<model ID>, ...):`.

Comment: The query is something like `insert into car_attributes(car_attr_id, fk_make_id,fk_model_id,year, body_type, mileage, price) values(car_attr_id_value,fk_make_id,.....)`

But as @sticky bit said **fk_make_id** column in car attributes not necessarily required as it can be derived from fk_model_id

Comment: @stickybit thank you for that tip, yes you correct, the user chooses the make from one JCombobox and the correct model for that make is displayed on another JCombobox, and those values already have IDs. I don't want to populate the IDS into a drop down because there's more than a thousand models IDs, only the makes of the cars which is filter by models, and I want to insert those names as foreign keys to the car_attribute table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this scenario came up when you want to add new car, so the GUI show you the *CAR_MAKEs*
when you choose, it will show you *CAR_MODELs*, then you need to **STORE** the ID of fetched data (car_makes OR car_models) in arrayList and use it in the query when the **USER** submit

**Just pseudo code**

```
int carMakesSelectedIndex = comboCarMakes.getSelectedIndex();    
int carModelsSelectedIndex = comboCarModels.getSelectedIndex();
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into car_attributes values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");  
stmt.setInt(1,carAttribute); 
stmt.setInt(2,carMakesIdList.get( carMakesSelectedIndex  ) ); 
stmt.setInt(3,carMakesIdList.get( carModelsSelectedIndex ) ); 
stmt.setString(4,carYear );
// the same with other attribute
```

Comment: could you please give me an example on how I can use the arrayList to accomplish that, if not asking for too much.

Comment: as you said before the car[makes, model] table are populated
first of all should you show the user car[makes, models]
fetch this data by normal query="SELECT * FROM car_makes" 
and then store it in arrayList like : 
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()){
     carMakesIdList.add( rs.getInt("make_id ") ); /*store id in list*/
     comboCarMakes.addItem( rs.getString("make ") ); /*add make into combo*/
}
you can also see [myJavaProject](https://github.com/elhoussam/AdministrationToolSQLServer) the only difference is connected with SqlServer

Comment: I have created the query to retrieve the car_makes as well as the models and also created the query to insert to values to the database, but I am having a problem when creating the ArrayList carMakesIdList to store the ID's in a list. This is what i wrote so far.  ArrayList<Integer> makesIdList = new ArrayList();
                
                for(int i = 0; i <makesIdList.size(); i++) {
               
                jComboBoxMake.addItem(makesIdList.get(i)); .

Comment: share the source code of that part, because am confused between VarNames

Comment: Hi Elshoussam, for the first answer you wrote, how did you come up with the carMakesIdList which gets the carMakesSelectedIndex. I think that is where I am getting confused until now. Could you please give me an example on how I can create the ArrayList in order to get IDs of car make and car model. Side note, the query query="SELECT * FROM car_makes" is in one Class which contains the JComboBox that fetches data from Database, and my INSERT query is on another Class inside a method.

Comment: @EmanuelGoncalves its **Simple interger List** like `ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();` the you populated it  with the car make IDs